# Kufr in friendship with kafirs

Tags: fiqh, hadith-interpretation, friendship

It is narrated in: https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:2378

> "A man is upon the religion of his friend, so let one of you look at whom he befriends."

From this narration, does it mean that if someone befriends a Christian, then his religion is Christianity? I've seen the questions and answers on here regarding the permissibility of friendships with kafirs in Islam, however, nobody has seemed to address this hadith. From it's apparent meaning, it comes off as saying that if u r friends with a kafir, u r a kafir. Is this true? Likewise, how does such a situation even work with a husband and his Christian/ Jewish wife? It seems almost impossible that Islam offers the concept and then condemns the one who acts in intimacy and closeness with them, even to the extent of it being kufr.